# Object Oriented Programming -> Operator

Tags: php, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

So I've been reading through the book *PHP Solutions, Dynamic Web Design Made Easy* by David Powers. I read through the short section on Object Oriented PHP, and I am having a hard time grasping the idea of the -> operator. Can anyone try to give me a solid explanation on the -> operator in OOP PHP?

Example:

```
$westcost = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$now->setTimezone($westcoast);
```

Also,a more general example:

```
$someObject->propertyName
```

Comment: it's just referencing a method or property of an object. Other languages use a dot for this operator. PHP couldn't because they used dot for string concat, hence the `->` instead.

Comment: @Spudley: just because it's simple to you, it may not be as clear-cut for other people :)

Comment: Oh, so it's equivalent to in java, 'System.out.println("hello");'

Comment: @oman9589 Exactly. In PHP, that'd be `$system->out->println("hello")` (if we assume that `$system` is an object, and that `$system->out` is an object as well)

Answer (score 0):

The `->` operator in PHP refers to either a function or a variable inside a class.

```
<?php
    class Example {
        public $variableInClass = "stringContent";
        public function functionInClass() {
            return "functionReturn";
        }
    }

    $example = new Example();
    var_dump($example->variableInClass); //stringContent
    var_dump($example->functionInClass()); //functionReturn
?>
```

Do note that if we're talking about static classes (different purpose), you use `::` instead:

```
<?php
    class Example {
        public static $variableInClass = "stringContent";
        public static function functionInClass() {
            return "functionReturn";
        }
    }

    var_dump($example::$variableInClass); //stringContent
    var_dump($example::functionInClass()); //functionReturn
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped quite a bit

Answer (score 0):

`$someObject->propertyName` can be read as:

**return** value stored in propertyName **from** object $someObject

`$someObject->methodName()` can be read as:

**execute**  methodName **from** object $someObject

Answer (score -1):

Classes and objects 101:

A class is defined as such:

```
class MyClass {

   public $value1;

   public function getValue() {

       return $this->value;

   }

}
```

We now defined a class with a single property, and a single function. To use these, we need to create an 'instance' of this object:

```
$myObject = new MyClass();
```

To use the property or function, we use the `->` operator:

```
echo $myObject->value1;
echo $myObject->getValue();
```

Put a little bit more abstractly.. the function `getValue` is defined in this object. By using the `->` operator on an instance of our class, what PHP does is effectively just call the function, just like any other function.. but before it gets called `$this` is assigned to the current object.

Hope this helps, if not.. I would simply recommend reading about OOP basics.

Comment: Not that `$this->value` would never return anything except for an error as it's not defined anywhere. It's probably just a typo though. :)