# What is the name of this operator: “->" in php?

Tags: php, oop, operators

i am php programmer but i don't know name of this operator

> ->
>   this operator use in OOP in php.
>   for example

```
$this->get();
```

Comment: This is an arrow and i think its taken to be pointer to reference properties

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448195/object-oriented-programming-operator)

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588149/what-is-the-php-operator-called-and-how-do-you-say-it-when-reading-code-out

Comment: I'm more interested in the name of `::` ;-)

Comment: @MarcelKorpel it's officially called a `Paamayim Nekudotayim` - translates to `double-colon` in hebrew ;)

Comment: you can know it in AlirezaFallah answer or [here](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php)

Comment: @Ryan Thanks, I already knew that, didn't knew it is from Hebrew, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the ***object operator*** (known as `T_OBJECT_OPERATOR` internally).

Answer (score 3):

The official name is **object operator**  :  [T_OBJECT_OPERATOR](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php).

Generally called  " **arrow** ".

Comment: i dont think the OP is too much concerned about what you call it :)

Comment: **'I'** here, does not mean '**I**' completely :)